# Bulletproof @Font-Face Syntax

Tags: css, wordpress, ftp

I'm trying to install a font via FTP and there is this error of wrong Bulletproof font-face syntax. Please, what am I doing wrong?

```css
@font-face {
font-family: 'Brasilero2018Free';
src: 
    url('/themes/fonts/Brasilero2018Free.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('/themes/fonts/Brasilero2018Free.woff') format('woff'),
    url('/themes/fonts/Brasilero2018Free.ttf') format('truetype'); 
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Maybe just a typo? Note, that where you define the address for the font, there’s `ttps://...` standing where it should read `https://...`.

Comment: Oh no, in the file it is https. It was just a wrong typo entering here in the question body

Comment: You're right - the paths are correct. Check you devtools: can you see any 404 errors in the console?  Do you have any custom permission rules set via FTP or by a security plugin. Have you tried the [elementor UI method to add fonts?](https://elementor.com/blog/custom-fonts/)

Comment: Yes I've tried and I ain't seeing any 404 errors.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your `@font-face` rule in css-live editor (extension).

There is a CORS issue (see the dev tools console):

> Access to font at
> 'https://www.flordeibez.org/wp-content/themes/fonts/Brasilero2018Free.woff2'
> from origin 'https://flordeibez.org' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

Your website's primary URL is `https://flordeibez.org` but your css references the `www` subdomain.

Changing your font src like solved the problem in my test.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Brasilero2018Free';
src: 
    url('https://flordeibez.org/wp-content/themes/fonts/Brasilero2018Free.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('https://flordeibez.org/wp-content/themes/fonts/Brasilero2018Free.woff') format('woff'),
    url('https://flordeibez.org/wp-content/themes/fonts/Brasilero2018Free.ttf') format('truetype'); 
}
```

Provided your `css` file is in your theme folder you could use relative paths like:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Brasilero2018Free';
src: 
    url('../fonts/Brasilero2018Free.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../fonts/Brasilero2018Free.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/Brasilero2018Free.ttf') format('truetype'); 
}
```

If this font-family doesn't include italics or other width you should specify fonst style and weight too:

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: 'Brasilero2018Free';
    src: 
        url('../fonts/Brasilero2018Free.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('../fonts/Brasilero2018Free.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/Brasilero2018Free.ttf') format('truetype'); 
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Keep in mind, you also need to apply the font-family to a HTML element - otherwise the browser won't load it.

E.g. apply it to the `<h1>` heading:

```
h1{
    font-family: 'Brasilero2018Free';
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

BTW. you can safely remove .eot (Internet Explorer only) and .svg fonts (not supported by Firefox or Chrome since years). Instead add the `woff2` version since it's the most compact format.

I also highly recommend to remove the `local()` rule as it can introduce issues in some browsers blocking locally installed fonts.

#### Issues with elementor specificity

Elementor and other page builder plugins tend to ad a lot of CSS specificity to font styles.

Workaround:
Install a plugin like [Custom Fonts](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-fonts/#description) to upload custom fonts in your admin area/media library.

Go to your theme customizer and open the Additional CSS drawer and add a custom rule using `!important` to override existing styles.

[image]

```
h1{
 font-family: 'Brasilero2018Free'!important;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: I keep trying but haven't succeed yet. Maybe it is the place where I'm inserting this css? I'm trying on .css file from my child theme folder.

Comment: Sorry but currently I cant't see any applied 'Brasilero2018Free'. Keep in mind that page builder plugins like elementor introduce a lot of CSS specificity. Inspecting your site shows `font-family: "Julius Sans One", Sans-serif;` defined as the `<h1>` font style. So I guess this family has been chosen on purpose via (style select) user input. If you need to override try `@font-face {font-family: 'Brasilero2018Free'; src: url('https://flordeibez.org/wp-content/themes/fonts/Brasilero2018Free.woff2') format('woff2')}
h1{font-family: 'Brasilero2018Free'!important; font-style: normal;}`

Comment: Frankly, I'm not a huge fan of page builders like elementor. However, I think your main problem is to apply relative paths and handle CSS specificity.  Although w3Cschool has not the best reputation (usually rather prefer a source like mdn docs) – I think this post summarized it pretty well. ["HTML File Paths"](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp)

Comment: It doesn't work yet. What a pity. I also don't like elementor but I haven't get there yet. Maybe someday I can build by code my own website. :) Well I've tried everything and bulletproof syntax still doesn't match.

Comment: I have the sneaky suspicion your child theme's css isn't loaded corrected. I've added another approach using a custom font plugin that might be helpful

Comment: I've tried with Custom Fonts plugin and it doesn't work. Oh my god.

Comment: Please go to your [wordpress settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oo4CL.png) and make sure the base URl is using `https://flordeibez.org`  - so *https* instead of *http.*  Go to the "Appearance/Custom fontst"  and delete the "Brasilero" entry.  After changing the baseURL to Https  reupload the font family. As mentioned before your child theme or custom css is nowhere applied you need to add a CSS style rule like `h1{font-family: 'Brasilero'!important; font-weight: 400;}` otherwise you won't see an effect.

Comment: So please focus on your custom CSS/child theme CSS - it's currently not applied at all. The `@font-face` rules and the font file paths work (apart from the aforementioned domain quirks https/http or with or without www.)

Answer (score 0):

With your syntax as:

```
src: url('some_url');
src: url('other_url');
```

you just redefine the URL for the font with every line. So browser will use only the last one, others are just discarded. The correct basic syntax is:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'SomeFont';
  src: 
    local("SomeFont"),
    url('//host.tld/SomeFont.woff2') format('woff2'), 
    url('//host.tld/SomeFont.woff') format('woff'), 
    url('//host.tld/SomeFont.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

You can include extra font formats if you need to satisfy old browsers.

NB: changed incorrect `format('ttf')` to `format('truetype')`, thanks to @herrstrietzel

Comment: Are only these 3 staying in code? And //host.tld is something I need to replace? I've tried a lot of things and nothing solve this.

Comment: Be careful: the  correct format for truetype fonts is `format('truetype')` (not "ttf"). @Flor de Ibez: you can use absolute paths but quite likely your font directory is located in your current theme folder i.e. `https://mywebsite.org/wp-content/themes/YOUR_THEME/fonts/Brasilero2018Free.woff2`. Check if this URL is correct by entering this URL in your address bar. If correct the browser will prompt to download this font file.

Comment: I'm using these 3 these days, all modern browsers support them. You might add eot/otf/svg formats if you have your font in corresponding format and want to support older browsers The `//host.tld...` is a URL to the font file.

Comment: @herrstrietzel fixed the answer, thank you. Additionally you don't have to specify hostname if you are serving your fonts from the same host and via same proto: `url('/path/to/file')`

Comment: I instelled the fonts in my "theme" folder, not in my astra theme folder, for example. I've just edited my post with the code I'm trying right now and it it is not working yet

Comment: Yes the url is correct once I can download it

Comment: Here's my try: 

`@font-face {
font-family: 'Brasilero2018Free';
src: 
    url('/themes/fonts/Brasilero2018Free.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('/themes/fonts/Brasilero2018Free.woff') format('woff'),
    url('/themes/fonts/Brasilero2018Free.ttf') format('truetype'); 
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}`